# function into mySQL, what am i missing?

Tags: php, mysql, function

I have a function to calculate some mathmatic, but it seems like it wont put into database...

Is there something i dont know or?

```
function overskud($odds, $indskud) {
    $overskud1 = $indskud * $odds;
    $overskud2 = $overskud1 - $indskud;
    echo "$overskud2";
}   
$overskud = overskud($odds, $indskud);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ODDS_kupon (kamp,odds,indskud,overskud,resultat,af,dato_ar,dato_moned,dato_dag) VALUES ('$kamp', '$odds', '$indskud', '$overskud2', '0', '$profilid', '$datoar', '$datomoned', '$datodag')");
```

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything, it just `echo`s its result.

Comment: $overskud does echo the result, for example 2, 100 returns me 100..

Comment: whats the `mysql_error()` ?

Comment: `echo` merely *outputs* a value to the screen.  `return` allows the value to be stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` the result rather than `echo` it:

```
function overskud($odds, $indskud) {
    $overskud1 = $indskud * $odds;
    $overskud2 = $overskud1 - $indskud;
    return "$overskud2";
}   
$overskud = overskud($odds, $indskud);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ODDS_kupon (kamp,odds,indskud,overskud,resultat,af,dato_ar,dato_moned,dato_dag) VALUES ('$kamp', '$odds', '$indskud', '$overskud2', '0', '$profilid', '$datoar', '$datomoned', '$datodag')");
```

You may need to alter this to `return` an array of values that includes `$overskud2` in addition to `$overskud`, since your `INSERT` query uses that variable (but unless it is defined elsewhere in code not posted, it is not in scope due to being inside the function).

`echo` simply outputs data to the page/buffer, `return` actually passes the value back to whatever invoked it and allows for variable assignment via function output.

Answer (score 0):

Your query uses the variable `$overskud2`, but you did not define it (it only exists *inside* the function). I suppose you meant `$overskud`.

And the function should `return` its result, not `echo` it (confused with shell scripting?).

Answer (score 0):

betr try this.. you should be returning something to the function call

```
function overskud($odds, $indskud) {
    $overskud1 = $indskud * $odds;
    $overskud2 = $overskud1 - $indskud;
    return $overskud2;
}   
$overskud = overskud($odds, $indskud);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ODDS_kupon(kamp,odds,indskud,overskud,resultat,af,dato_ar,dato_moned,dato_dag) VALUES('$kamp','$odds', '$indskud', '$overskud', '0', '$profilid', '$datoar', '$datomoned', '$datodag')");
```